# I can't reference tkinter entry widget values correctly

Tags: pandas, tkinter

I can't seem to retrieve entered values in an entry widget to write to excel file

So this function works fine to update treeview

```
def update_record():
    # Grab record number
    selected = my_tree.focus()
    # Update Record
    # my_tree.item(selected, text="", values=(fl_spinbox.get(), cnt_entry.get(),))
    # my_tree.item(selected, text="", values=(record[5], record[6],))
    my_tree.set(selected, "fenceLabel", fl_spinbox.get())
    my_tree.set(selected, "Comment",cnt_entry.get())

    # Insert row into treeview
    my_tree.insert('', tk.END, values=fl_spinbox)
    my_tree.insert('', tk.END, values=cnt_entry)

    # Clear entry boxes
    fl_spinbox.delete(0, END)
    cnt_entry.delete(0, END)#
```

But when I use the following function to get the same entry widgets I get an error stating: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

```
def save_record():
    excel_file = "fallers_output.xlsx"
    faller_file = Path.cwd() / excel_file

    # Set Output file
    df = pd.read_excel(faller_file)

    # Get primary key to use against df
    selected = my_tree.focus()

    if selected:
        primary_key = my_tree.item(selected)['values'][0]

        if primary_key in df["fallerId"].values:
        # Get the index of the row with the primary key
            index = df.index[df["fallerId"] == int(primary_key)]

            # Get button entry values
            new_fl_value = fl_spinbox.get()
            new_cnt_value = cnt_entry.get()

            print("Age string:", fl_spinbox.get())  # Debug print
            print("ID:", cnt_entry.get())  # Debug print

            df.at[index, "fenceLabel"] = int(new_fl_value)
            df.at[index, "Comment"] = new_cnt_value

            # Write to excel 
            df.to_excel(faller_file, index=False)

            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Values replaced and saved to Excel file successfully!")

        # Update Treeview display
        my_tree.item(index, values=(new_fl_value, new_cnt_value))  # Update displayed values
        fl_spinbox.delete(0, tk.END)
        cnt_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Primary key not found in DataFrame")
```

I'm seeing the values be populated in the treeview when tkinter window is open but just not updating as expected.

```
<ipython-input-8-e0949f9e101c>:109: FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`
  my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[0], record[3], record[4], record[8], record[13], record[15], record[16], record[17]), tags=('evenrow',))
<ipython-input-8-e0949f9e101c>:111: FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`
  my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[0], record[3], record[4], record[8], record[13], record[15], record[16], record[17]), tags=('oddrow',))
Age string: 
ID: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\evaughan\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\fallers\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\evaughan\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\fallers\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "<ipython-input-12-5f1b7a09a2d5>", line 27, in save_record
    df.at[index, "fenceLabel"] = int(new_fl_value)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Record Entry Boxes

```
fl_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
fl_spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(data_frame, from_=1, to=27)
fl_spinbox.insert(0, "1-27")
fl_spinbox.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")
```

````
cnt_label = Label(data_frame, text="Comment")
cnt_label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
cnt_entry = Entry(data_frame)
cnt_entry.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)```
````

Comment: It is better to post a [mre] and the full error traceback as it shows on which line the exception is raised.

Comment: At a glance, `my_tree.insert('', tk.END, values=fl_spinbox)` and `my_tree.insert('', tk.END, values=cnt_entry)` should probably both use `fl_spinbox.get()` and `cnt_entry.get()` (respectively) - as written, you're `insert`ing the widgets themselves, not their values

Comment: The traceback shows that `new_fl_value` is an empty string.  It is proved also in the console output `Age string:`

Comment: @JRiggles My issue is with the second function, the first one shared does as expected and inputs the values entered into there correct cell value in the treeview, the issue with second function `save_record()` is that it doesn't reference these values correctly

Comment: @acw1668, nothing at all
Age string:  & ID:

Comment: @acw1668 no output, which is strange

Comment: So I have tried to get the first column value in the treeview (primary_key) which should match that of dataframe (fallerId) upon which I want to write out to.

Comment: It is nothing related to the treeview.  The traceback tells that there is nothing in the entry `fl_spinbox` (assume it is an entry widget).

Comment: Added entry boxes created above

Comment: If not using `StringvVar` for `Spinbox` 's widget, that will cause ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' So see my answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139678/binding-spinbox-to-textbox/78140792#78140792

Comment: I think my issue has been deleting the values in the first function `fl_spinbox.delete(0, END)` & `cnt_entry.delete(0, END)`. After commenting this out I get values returned Age string: 5 & ID: Test2 but now get a different error of `raise InvalidIndexError(
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: You can only assign a scalar value not a <class 'int'>` which I would say has to do with dtype of spinbox

Comment: Does m,y answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993666/how-to-set-and-get-the-value-of-a-tkinter-spinbox-in-a-child-window-correctly/77994993#77994993